# PHP IP Whitelist

Tags: php, html

When i try to execute the code below it just doesn't redirect like it should be because my ip isn't equal to those. Not sure what i'm doing wrong here.

```
<?php
    $whitelist = array('111.111.111.112', '111.111.111.112');
    if (in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $whitelist)) {
        //Action for allowed IP Addresses
    } else {
        header("Location: http://www.redirect.to.url.com/");
    }
    echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
?>
<html>
   <body>
      <form action = "upload.php" method = "POST" enctype = "multipart/form-data">
         <input type = "file" name = "image" />
         <input type = "submit"/>   
      </form>

   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why are there the same IP addresses in the array? Did you check for errors also? Plus, why the form?

Comment: Changed the ips and still nothing. Don't think there are any errors.

Comment: What does `print_r($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);` give?

Comment: Hi, in PHP after a `header` for redirection you need to `exit` the script, so add `exit();` after the `header()` call. Also you must not output anything before `header()` in order for any HTTP header to work.

Comment: Added exit(); and it didn't work, but when i try to add the print it doesn't do anything.

Comment: I tested your original code, it does redirect both in apache2 and iis10 servers in Google Chrome browser.

Comment: may be something with me htaccess or apache2.